# How to check for new files in a folder in python

Tags: python, automation, schedule

I am trying to create a script that will be executed every 10 minutes. Each time I have to check if there are new files in specific folder in my computer and if yes, there are some functions that would run on this file in order to get some values. These values will be written to excel file. The problem is that every time this function will be executed, the variables that contain the path to all the files will be generated again, and the program will go over all the files. How can I handle this problem?
Thanks

Comment: The WatchDog package is your friend. See here: https://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/

Answer (score 8):

```
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler

class MyHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_any_event(self, event):
        print(event.event_type, event.src_path)

    def on_created(self, event):
        print("on_created", event.src_path)
        print(event.src_path.strip())
        if((event.src_path).strip() == ".\test.xml"):        
            print("Execute your logic here!")

event_handler = MyHandler()
observer = Observer()
observer.schedule(event_handler, path='.', recursive=False)
observer.start()


while True:
    try:
        pass
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
```

1. pip install watchdog
2. Create a scheduled task for this script in the Task scheduler and monitor the folder where the file will be created.

Comment: Did you mean to type `r".\test.xml"`? `\t` is a special symbol (tab) and is uncommon in the file names.

Comment: By \t I did not mean tab in the file name. In the above example r".\test.xml", text.xml is the file name and ".\" means current folder

Answer (score 5):

Start by initializing variables:

```
savedSet=set()
mypath=… #YOUR PATH HERE
```

At the end of each cycle, save a set of file names, creation times and sizes in tuple format to another variable. When retrieving files, do the following:

-Retrieve a set of file paths

```
nameSet=set()
for file in os.listdir(path):
    fullpath=os.path.join(mypath, file)
    if os.path.isfile(fullpath):
        nameSet.add(file)
```

-Create tuples

```
retrievedSet=set()
for name in nameSet:
    stat=os.stat(os.path.join(mypath, name))
    time=ST_CTIME
    #size=stat.ST_SIZE If you add this, you will be able to detect file size changes as well.
    #Also consider using ST_MTIME to detect last time modified
    retrievedSet.add((name,time))
```

-Compare set with saved set to find new files

```
newSet=retrievedSet-savedSet
```

-Compare set with saved set to find removed files

```
deletedSet=savedSet-retrievedSet
```

-Run your functions on files with names from newSet
-Update saved set

```
savedSet=newSet
```

Comment: Possibly this should be time=stat.ST_CTIME ?

Comment: If I recall correctly, it depends on how you import stat. But yes, it probably should.

Answer (score 3):

```
import operator
from stat import ST_CTIME
import os, sys, time
path = str(os.getcwd()) + '/' ;  #or you can assign the return value of your 
                                 #function (the updated path as per your question) 
                                 #which operates on the file 'new_file'  to this variable. 
files = os.listdir(path);

def mostRecentFile(path):
    all_files = os.listdir(path);
    file_ctime = dict();
    for file in all_files:
        file_times[e] = time.time() - os.stat(e).st_ctime;
    return  sorted(file_times.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0][0]

new_file = mostRecentFile(path)
```

The code returns only one file, which is the newest in the directory (as per your requirement). The variable `new_file` has the file name returned by the function `mostRecentFile`, which is the one most recently created in the present directory given by the variable `path`. You can tweak that to change how you want the path to be fed - current working directory or by changing to the desired directory. Given to your requirement, I think you want the current directory, and the same is used by the code.

I have considered creation time by using `st_ctime`. You can use the modification time by replacing `st_ctime` with `st_mtime`.

You can pass this newly created file `new_file` to your function, and assign the new path that is generated by this function to the variable `path`.

Comment: cant get this code to work in anyway

Answer (score 1):

first, run for the first time this script in your directory to create a "files" file

```
import os
import pandas as pd
list_of_files=os.listdir()
list_of_files.append('files.csv')

pd.DataFrame({'files':list_of_files}).to_csv('files.csv')
```

then in your main script add this:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

files=pd.read_csv('files.csv')
list_of_files=os.listdir()

if len(files.files)!=len(list_of_files):
    #do what you want
    #save your excel with the name sample.xslx
    #append your excel into list of files and get the set so you will not have the sample.xlsx twice if run again
    list_of_files.append('sample.xslx')
    list_of_files=list(set(list_of_files))
    #save again the curent list of files 
    pd.DataFrame({'files':list_of_files}).to_csv('files.csv')
```